# Need a regex to restrict to a alphanumeric string or -25 or -10 for Schema simpleType

Tags: regex, schema

I need a regex that would allow for an alphanumeric string or -25 or -10.  For example, it would allow P124T or 20 or -25 or -10, but not allow -22 or -20.

Sort of like the union of a string and -25 and -10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]*|-25|-20)$
```

the (a|b|c) syntax basically says 'match one of a, b or c'

Comment: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]|-25|-20)+$ won't work for P23-4, so how would I allow P23-4 but not -22 or -10?

Comment: looks like this will do it: ^(-20)$|^(-25)$|^[^-][\w\W]*

Comment: Have edited the above to allow matches such as P23-4. It checks that the match begins with a letter or number

Comment: Okay, now I'm having the issue that the expression doesn't work in schema:  <xs:pattern value="^([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]*|-25|-20)$"/>

Comment: Resolved: Schema regex doesn't use the anchors.  See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html